# Which distribution of python?

Tags: python, version

How do I tell which distribution I am using?
E.g. my version line says:

3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Is that CPython? PyPy? Jython? etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I detect if my code is running on cPython or Jython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103487/can-i-detect-if-my-code-is-running-on-cpython-or-jython)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `platform` module on python versions above 2.6.

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_implementation()
```

This will return 'CPython' for the C implementation, 'IronPython' for IronPython, 'Jython' for the Java implementation, and 'PyPy' for the PyPy version.